# Unable to interact with Smart Contract using Ethereum node Javascript console

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, private-blockchain

I deployed a smart contract and to interact with that I've written Javascript.

When I use loadScript('requestor.js') in my geth console

I'm getting the following error

[image]

Line 236 in my code is

```
const readline = require('readline');
```

but when I compile readline usage example code from nodejs its working fine.

ex:

```
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What do you think of Node.js? ', (answer) => {
  // TODO: Log the answer in a database
  console.log(`Thank you for your valuable feedback: ${answer}`);

  rl.close();
});
```

I'm new to Javascript. I don't know whether readline is removed from my node version 9.11.2 or geth javascript is not supporting it?

Comment: About language issues it is better to ask in stackoverflow.com directly.

Comment: Yes i know but when i compile readline example in nodejs console its working fine. But when use the same in my geth web3 console im getting an error. I think its related web3 version or web3 library something like that.....

Comment: OK, I understand now. The problem is that geth use a reduced javascript interpreter so it is possible some features required by readline are not available.

Comment: For example in particular `const` is not supported by geth's console.

Comment: But i need to take input from user and display some outputs in the console. Is there any option other than readline?

Comment: You can run your script in a separate node instance and connect to geth through and http provider. Take a look at https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/web3-eth.html.

Comment: Now im getting new error while running in a node istance. Error is "undefined  1 SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (~/requestor.js:234:19)" . Line 234 is "var accAbi = JSON.parse(web3.utils.hexToAscii(accAbiBytes));"  var methodName = "Method1";
var register = web3.eth.Contract(regAbi, regAddr);
var accAddr = register.methods.getContractAddr(methodName);
var accAbiBytes = web3.utils.bytesToHex(register.methods.getContractAbi(methodName));
var accAbi = JSON.parse(web3.utils.hexToAscii(accAbiBytes));

Comment: I'd recommend to create a new question since it is unrelated to this one.